# PHP - Upload CSV data in custom Wordpress database

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, csv, file-upload

**my_custom_table:**

```
id              int(11)
product_type    varchar(210)
product_serial  varchar(210)
created_at      datetime


//Upload CSV File
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

        if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['upload_csv']['tmp_name'])) {

                echo "<h1>" . "File ". $_FILES['upload_csv']['name'] ." uploaded successfully." . "</h1>";
        }


        //Import uploaded file to Database
        $handle = fopen($_FILES['upload_csv']['tmp_name'], "r");

        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
            $wpdb->insert("my_custom_table", array(
                    "product_type" => $data[0],
                    "product_serial" => $data[1],
                    "created_at" => current_time('mysql', 1)
                 ));
        }

        fclose($handle);

        print "Import done";
}
```

**Print `$data` output with delimiter `,`:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Product Name;product_serial
)

Array
(
    [0] => iPhone 6;iphone-002
)

Array
(
    [0] => iPhone 6;iphone-003
)
```

**Print `$data` output with delimiter `;`:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Product Name
    [1] => product_serial
)

Array
(
    [0] => iPhone 6
    [1] => iphone-002
)

Array
(
    [0] => iPhone 6
    [1] => iphone-003
)
```

Using above, `Product Name` and `product_serial` also gets inserted in DB which should be prevented. Also delimiter `,`  does not output correct array while `;` does.

How can I prevent CSV column names insertion and insert correct value in Database?

P.S: Using OpenOffice for CSV data insertion. Could formatting be an issue with delimiter ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general rule of thumb is the first line of CSV is the column names, therefore a quick skip counter will remove the first row for you:

```
$counter = 0;
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {

    // Skip the first row as is likely column names
    if ($counter === 0) {
        $counter++;
        continue;
    }

    // Insert the row into the database
    $wpdb->insert("my_custom_table", array(
        "product_type" => $data[0],
        "product_serial" => $data[1],
        "created_at" => current_time('mysql', 1)
    ));
}
```

The other problem is CSV files can have varying column and row delimiters (AKA sometimes columns are sperated by comma, and other times semi colons ...etc) making parsing CSV quite difficult. I this example it seems your column delimiter is semi-colon so modifying your function parameters may fix it for you:

```
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ";")) !== FALSE) {
```

If you really must support multiple types of delimiter, the following code snippet may help you:

```
$csvFilePath = $_FILES['upload_csv']['tmp_name'];
$delimiter = $this->detectDelimiter($csvFilePath);

public function detectDelimiter($csvFile)
{
    $delimiters = array(
        ';' => 0,
        ',' => 0,
        "\t" => 0,
        "|" => 0
    );

    $handle = fopen($csvFile, "r");
    $firstLine = fgets($handle);
    fclose($handle); 
    foreach ($delimiters as $delimiter => &$count) {
        $count = count(str_getcsv($firstLine, $delimiter));
    }

    return array_search(max($delimiters), $delimiters);
}
```

Detect snippet taken from: [HERE](https://coderwall.com/p/qsldcq/php-csv-autodetect-delimiter)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Skip counter removes the first row i.e. column names but did not get your snippet about delimiters. How could I implement the same in my code snippet ?

Comment: Revised my answer, it seems detecting the delimiter is quite tricky and many posts suggest asking the user to provide it with the CSV file. I have revised my answer which will fix your CSV problem, but if you CSVs have varying delimiters (AKA comma and/or semi colon) then you are in for a rocky ride.... Goodluck.